# jQuery Interpret text in textarea as selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a website with a textarea.
My idea is, on the website, to post plain text like this example inside a textarea:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Teste</h1>
    <p><img src="/test.png"> Ola</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Like this image: [image]

That's how the users will past the "HTML Code" inside the textarea on the website

My objective is to find all the (for example) `img` tags, and get their `src` content. Is there a way to find the `img` tag with jQuery like one would normally do on their code like this: `$('.container').find('img')` ?

Or is the only way to find the index of the `<img` and start from there doing substrings and storing the data?

Comment: There is no textarea in your example. To find images, you could just do $("img")

Comment: You can't have that exact text inside a `textarea`. The text should be encoded, so it would start `&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;` Therefore you're going to need to get the text, replace the entities, then parse as HTML, and finally use jQuery to find the elements within.

Comment: @juvian, this HTML will be inside the textarea. That's what he meant. He wants to find all the `img` tags _as text_ from inside of it.

Comment: I've edited the question to be more clarifying. Sorry

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Do I necessarily need to replace the entities? Can't I just parse the text as HTML?
Juvians answer below works just fine like that.

Comment: No, I was thinking of earlier versions of HTML. More recent versions allow most HTML elements. You're not *supposed* to be able to put `DOCTYPE`, `html`, `head` or `body` in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var html = $("textarea").val();
console.log($(html).find("img").attr("src"))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Teste</h1>
    <p><img src="/test.png"> Ola</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a DOM element in memory, load your html text into that, and then operate on that like any other DOM element.

Example

```js
var div = document.createElement("div")
div.innerHTML = document.getElementById("1337").textContent
console.log($(div).find('img')[0].src)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="1337" class="mytext" width=100px height=100px>
&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;
&lt;html&gt;
&lt;head&gt;
   &lt;title&gt;Example&lt;/title&gt;
&lt;/head&gt;
&lt;body&gt;
&lt;div class=&quot;container&quot;&gt;
    &lt;h1&gt;Teste&lt;/h1&gt;
    &lt;p&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;/test.png&quot;&gt; Ola img&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/body&gt;
&lt;/html&gt;
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var html = $("textarea").val();
    $src=$(html).find("img").attr("src");
    $('button').click(function(){

    $('#pk').attr('src',$src);
    });
```

```html
    <img id='pk' src="">
    <button>click</button>
    <textarea></textarea>
```

You can use a button to view that image in age itself like this